# Show that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: general-topology, finite-groups, topological-groups, normal-subgroups, p-groups

> Let $ p $ be a fast number and $ (G, \cdot) $ a finite p-group. Show that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $ H \cap Z (G) \neq \left \{I_ {G}\right \}.$ (Here $Z (G)$ is the $G$ centralizer.)

I think there is a theorem that if a $p$-group is finite, then $| G |$ is it's a $p$-power. I think there is a theorem Sylow that if a $p$-group is finite, then $| G |$ is it's a $p$-power.

Comment: I assume you mean $p$ is prime and $H$ is nontrivial?

Comment: @Bungo Exactly s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean that $p$ is a **prime** number, and also assume that $H$ is nontrivial.

Let $G$ act on $H$ by conjugation. Then the orbit-stabilizer theorem gives us
$$|H| = \text{# of one-point orbits} + \sum (\text{sizes of nontrivial orbits})$$
Now $h \in H$ is in a one-point orbit iff $ghg^{-1} = h$ for every $g \in G$, iff $gh = hg$ for every $g \in G$, if and only if $h \in H \cap Z(G)$. Therefore,
$$|H| = |H \cap Z(G)| + \sum (\text{sizes of nontrivial orbits})$$
Now compute this equation modulo $p$. Since $G$ is a $p$-group, we have $|H|$ is a power of $p$, so $|H| \equiv 0\ (\operatorname{mod} p)$. Also, the size of any orbit is a divisor of $|G|$, so the size of each nontrivial orbit is also $0$ mod $p$. Thus the equation reduces to
$$0 \equiv |H \cap Z(G)| + 0\ (\operatorname{mod} p)$$
Since $H \cap Z(G)$ is nonempty (it contains the identity), this means that $|H \cap Z(G)|$ is at least $p$, hence $H \cap Z(G)$ is nontrivial.